# How to include regex in the css selector in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying the extract the text by using the CSS selector. as variables are dynamic in nature they are continuously updating.

```
#profileCard-ACoAABI4A30BKLei-DtaS6B6vQo-3ejw-nzI1W8-EDUCATION-en-US 

this is a CSS selector

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#profileCard-ACoAABI4A30BKLei-DtaS6B6vQo-3ejw-nzI1W8-EDUCATION-en-US').text

x_path = //*[@id="profileCard-ACoAABI4A30BKLei-DtaS6B6vQo-3ejw-nzI1W8-EDUCATION-en-US"]
# here i tried to apply the regex
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[ends-with(@id,'EDUCATION-en-US')]")
```

But I'm getting an error as 'InvalidSelectorException'.
Is there any way to get the data without error?

'ACoAABI4A30BKLei-DtaS6B6vQo-3ejw-nzI1W8' this path will be continuously updating.
'#profileCard', 'EDUCATION-en-US' there will be no change in this

Any help or lead to solve the issue would be very helpful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do what you are looking for:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[id^="profileCard-"][id$="-EDUCATION-en-US"]').text
```

The `^` denotes what the `id` should begin with.

The `$` denotes what the `id` should end with.

Answer (score 0):

For value of *id* attributes like:

```
#profileCard-ACoAABI4A30BKLei-DtaS6B6vQo-3ejw-nzI1W8-EDUCATION-en-US
```

*xpath* doesn't supports *`ends-with()`*. Instead you can use either of the following options:

- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[starts-with(@id, 'profileCard') and contains(@id, 'EDUCATION-en-US')]").text
  ```
- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[id^='profileCard'][id$='EDUCATION-en-US']").text
  ```

Comment: Suppose if we have  `Xpath = //*[@id="ember265"]/div/div/div[1] ` like this where numbers are dynamic and this is XPath is independent of class and id. Then what is way to implement regex here

Comment: **`ember*`** indicates a dynamic element. You have to construct the locator considering that.

Comment: currenty i am using this. `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'ember')]/div/div/div[1]").text` but it returning a empty list.

Comment: Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.